# Remove columns from data.frame that are of type list

Tags: r, list, dataframe, subset

Given a data.frame that has list columns and trying to write it to a csv file, how can a user drop all columns of type list?

dput would be quite long. See an example here
Note that full df has 5+ list columns and I prefer not enumerating them or hunting them by name.

```
> str(df,max.level=1)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   2237 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ CATEGORY    : chr  "ARTICLE " "ARTICLE " "ARTICLE " "ARTICLE " ...
 $ BIBTEXKEY   : chr  "RN69" "RN4023" "RN3332" "RN58" ...
 $ ADDRESS     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ ANNOTE      : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AUTHOR      :List of 2237
 $ BOOKTITLE   : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 and 40+ other columns

> names(df)
 [1] "CATEGORY"     "BIBTEXKEY"    "ADDRESS"      "ANNOTE"       "AUTHOR"       "BOOKTITLE"   
 [7] "CHAPTER"      "CROSSREF"     "EDITION"      "EDITOR"       "HOWPUBLISHED" "INSTITUTION" 
[13] "JOURNAL"      "KEY"          "MONTH"        "NOTE"         "NUMBER"       "ORGANIZATION"
[19] "PAGES"        "PUBLISHER"    "SCHOOL"       "SERIES"       "TITLE"        "TYPE"        
[25] "VOLUME"       "YEAR"         "ISSN"         "DOI"          "ISBN"         "URL"         
>
```

the command should looke something like

`df %>% select_if(!is.list)` but it is not fully correct

df comes from

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/bib2df")
library(bib2df)
url <- "https://cprd.com/bibliography/export/bibtex"
df <- bib2df(url)
```

this selects them correctly but negation seems hard to do

```
df %>% select_if(is_list)
```

Comment: Are you sure in a data.frame columns can be of type list?

Comment: Hi UserJT, can you make this a minimum reproducible example with for example `dput` so we can see your data frame? Thanks :)

Comment: @akash87 `nested` data frames can contain lists(I think).

Comment: something like  `mtcars %>% select_if(!is.numeric)`

Comment: Just use `unnest(AUTHOR)` I think and then remove it. Better to add data with `dput`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to use logical indexing:

```
  df[,!purrr::map_lgl(df,is.list)] %>% 
   names()
 [1] "CATEGORY"     "BIBTEXKEY"    "ADDRESS"      "ANNOTE"       "BOOKTITLE"   
 [6] "CHAPTER"      "CROSSREF"     "EDITION"      "HOWPUBLISHED" "INSTITUTION" 
[11] "JOURNAL"      "KEY"          "MONTH"        "NOTE"         "NUMBER"      
[16] "ORGANIZATION" "PAGES"        "PUBLISHER"    "SCHOOL"       "SERIES"      
[21] "TITLE"        "TYPE"         "VOLUME"       "YEAR"         "ISSN"        
[26] "DOI"          "ISBN"         "URL"
```

You can also do `df %>% select_if(Negate(is.list))`

Also, As mentioned by @akrun,
You can simply use `discard` from `purrr`:

```
purrr::discard(dat, is.list)
```

Or as @markus points out, we can use `keep` and `negate`:

```
keep(dat, negate(is.list))
```

Otherwise:

We can unnest:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  unnest(AUTHOR) %>% 
  select(-AUTHOR)
```

Comment: good but I need to unnest by a !is.list criterion. Off course I had `df %>% select(TITLE,DOI,TYPE,YEAR) %>% write_csv('cprd-pubs.csv')`

Answer (score 4):

Given

```
dat <- tibble::tibble(a = 1,
                      b = list(d = c(1, 2)))
```

we can use

```
Filter(Negate(is.list), dat)
```

to get

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#      a
#  <dbl>
#1     1
```

---

Typing `Negate` into the console we see what it does

```
function (f) 
{
    f <- match.fun(f)
    function(...) !f(...)
}
```

Comment: Just curious, why does `!` fails  with `is.list` in `Filter`? Tried it but it failed.

Comment: I can only quote the help page: "`Negate` creates the negation of a given function." while "`!` indicates logical negation (NOT)." Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: *fail. Thanks, strange. Maybe this fits OP's aim: `df %>% 
  select_if(Negate(is.list))`

Comment: @NelsonGon Or `library(purrr); keep(dat, negate(is.list))` if you want to stay in the tidyverse.

Comment: Thanks. Edited to add this option too. Glad to learn about `negate`.